# displaying a text on top left, before textarea

Tags: html, css

this is my first time working with html and css so i'm having a bit of a problem. i am trying to create a textbox that will allow user to input some text, but the title of textbox is positioned on the bottom somehow.

here is what it currently looks like:

[image]

i want the "Notes:" to be on top left instead of being at the bottom

```html
<br>Notes:
<textarea name="patientNotes" style="width: 250px;
    height: 100px; 
    text-align: left;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-top:0;
    padding-bottom:0.4em;
    padding-right: 0.4em;">
    </textarea><br/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
Looking for this:
<br>
<br>

<div>Notes:</div>
<textarea name="patientNotes" 
style="width: 250px;
height: 100px; 
text-align: left;
padding-left:0;
padding-top:0;
padding-bottom:0.4em;
padding-right: 0.4em;">
</textarea><br/>
<br>
Or for this:
<br>
<br>

<div style="display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap;">Notes:
<textarea name="patientNotes" 
style="width: 250px;
height: 100px; 
text-align: left;
padding-left:0;
padding-top:0;
padding-bottom:0.4em;
padding-right: 0.4em;">
</textarea><br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a fieldset - for other version see the other answers

```css
.ta {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0.4em;
  padding-right: 0.4em;
  border:0;
}

fieldset {
  width: 254px
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Notes:</legend>
  <textarea name="patientNotes" class="ta"></textarea>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply add style: `vertical-align: top` to `text-area`:

```html
<br>Notes:
<textarea name="patientNotes" style="width: 250px;
    height: 100px; 
    text-align: left;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-top:0;
    padding-bottom:0.4em;
    padding-right: 0.4em;
    vertical-align: top">
    </textarea><br/>
```